# Write a function that displays all the different combinations of three different digits

Tags: c, bash, function

my function my_putchar

```
#include <unistd.h>
void my_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

my function my_print_comb

```
#include <unistd.h>
int my_putchar(char c);
void my_print_comb(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    for(i = 48; i <= 57; ++i)
    {
        my_putchar(i);
        for(j = 48; j <= 57; ++j)
        {
            for(k = 48; j <= 57; ++k)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}

my_putchar(',');
my_putcahr(' ');
my_putchar('\n');
}
```

and my main:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int my_print_comb(void);
int main ()
{
    my_print_comb();
    return (0);
}
```

So i want to write all combi of in order with a ./ex | cat -e

```
the combi 012, 013, 014, ..., 789$
```

i try with this function but i write only bug like : A@^

Comment: Don't you think adding the definition of `my_putchar` is relevant?

Comment: Hint: print all 3 `i`, `j`, and `k` inside the most inner loop.

Comment: sure i can had my_putchar look i edit my post

Comment: Have you tried this code at all? 1) It can't compile 2) What is my_putcahr? 3) When the compilation error is fixed, there's an endless loop

Comment: Whatever code outputs `A@^` the code presented in your question is not it.  Post the actual code; we cannot help with errors in code unseen.

Comment: Why does your _wanted_ output start `012` and end in `789`? There is something missing in your specification.  Perhaps you want "all combinations of _unique_ digits?  Even then the last value would be `987`, not `789`.  It is not at all clear what you want.

Comment: @Clifford, I understood the second "different" in the subject to mean that the three digits are all different. It explains the first and last values in the expected output. (I assume that the order in which the numbers are printed isn't critical, _i.e._ that the output is expected to include both `789` and `987`.)

Comment: @TimRandall possibly, but the broken code is not even close to that, and your answer does not do that either.  Besides, it is not a matter of your or my understanding, it is a matter of making an unambiguous question, even if your assumptions are correct, the question still needs fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop was testing against the wrong variable. You weren't printing the three digits in the inner loop. I also switched to using the character constants '0' and '9' to make it easier to read and error-check the code. (I presume the typo `putcahr` wasn't in your original code.)

Edited to add: Sorry, I missed the word "different" in the question. I'll leave the exact implementation of that as an exercise for the reader, since you didn't post any code attempting to check for it. But adding one `if` check around the inner block of code should do it: `if(test){my_putchar(i); my_putchar(j);...}`

```
void my_print_comb(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    for(i = '0'; i <= '9'; ++i)
    {
        for(j = '0'; j <= '9'; ++j)
        {
            for(k = '0'; k <= '9'; ++k) // k, not j, is tested against '9'
            {
                my_putchar(i);
                my_putchar(j);
                my_putchar(k);
                my_putchar(',');
                my_putchar(' ');
            }
        }
    }
}
```